# Accessing an Ember component properties from DOM

Tags: ember.js

When creating integration tests for my Ember components I can pick up fired actions (aka, with `on` handler) and text properties set in the DOM (aka, with `$(target).text().trim()`). I can even pass in a bound value and watch it's value change so long as it's a two-way binding (aka, `{{my-comp value=value}}`). But what I often want to do is observe a property within the component without binding to it. With a unit test this would be easy but unit tests are quite awkward in many ways so I'm trying to accomplish most my testing needs in integration tests these days.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

> p.s. the Ember Inspector seems to indicate that what I'm trying to achieve is definitely possible

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to test internals. You're testing the integration of a components public api.

Comment: yes that is true to an extent but with UT's fairly awkward these days with a "needs" convention that is going away I am tempted by what I know must be possible. :)

Comment: The ember inspector is an ember app in itself. If you want to test component properties that aren't visible in the dom  you ll have to do it in a unit test.

Comment: @Kitler sure, my point is that an app (aka, Inspector) CAN access methods and properties of an ember object and therefore so too can an integration test. Whether its a good idea to do that is a reasonable question.